# C++17 pointer array to a std::any of tuple

Tags: c++, c++17

I am writing a function that stores a parameter pack into a `std::any` of tuple, and I need to allocate a pointer array `void* arguments[]` to each item of the tuple. How can I do that at compile time?

```
template <typename... ArgsT>
void func(ArgsT&&... args) {
  // any will be the storage for the argument
  std::any any = std::make_tuple(std::forward<ArgsT>(args)...);

  // here I need a pointer array with each ptrs[i] to (void*)&std::get<i>( std::get<WhatTupleTypeHere?>(any) )
  
  void* arguments[sizeof...(ArgsT)] = { ??? };  
}
```

For example, if I have:

```
fun(1, 2.4, std::string("hello"))
```

Then arguments should go as follows:

```
std::any storage = std::tuple<int, float, std::string>(1, 2.4, "hello");

auto& tuple = std::tuple<int, float, std::string>>(storage);

void* arguments[3] = {
  (void*)&std::get<0>(tuple),
  (void*)&std::get<1>(tuple),
  (void*)&std::get<2>(tuple)
};
```

My compiler supports c++17.

Comment: Um, why exactly do you need that? What's the point of having an `any` if you're just going to use a `void*`? You may as well just heap allocate the `tuple` and get `void*`s to it and to the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full example including test cases with a few minor changes (e.g., `static` in `func`) to help with testing/lifetime issues, but I think I hit your requirements.

```
#include <any>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

namespace {
    namespace detail {
        template <std::size_t INDEX, typename ...Ts>
        void fill_array(void ** arguments, std::tuple<Ts...> & data) {
            if constexpr(INDEX < sizeof...(Ts)) {
                arguments[INDEX] = (void *)&std::get<INDEX>(data);
                fill_array<INDEX + 1>(arguments, data);
            }
        }
    }

    template <typename... ArgsT>
        void** func(ArgsT&&... args) {
        // any will be the storage for the argument
        static std::any any = std::make_tuple(std::forward<ArgsT>(args)...);

        // here I need a pointer array with each ptrs[i] to (void*)&std::get<i>( std::get<WhatTupleTypeHere?>(any) )

        static void* arguments[sizeof...(ArgsT)];
        detail::fill_array<0>(arguments, std::any_cast<std::tuple<ArgsT...>&>(any));
        return arguments;
    }
}

int main() {
    auto arguments = func(1, 2.4, std::string("hello"));
    std::cout << *((int*)arguments[0]) << '\n'
              << *((double*)arguments[1]) << '\n'
              << *((std::string*)arguments[2]) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

The trick is to use `fill_array` since we need compile-time constants when using `std::get`.  We'll extract the `tuple` from your `any`, and then it's fairly straightforward code as far as `template`s go.

Comment: You really ought to use an index list rather than recursion. And you could just return an `array<void*, size>` instead of creating the array in an uninitialized state.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Stack Overflow allows multiple answers. This looks like working code, so it's a reasonable answer. You may be right that there's another, better solution, but we can't judge that from just a comment.